# Keep only last 5 search results of user in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, rows, sql-delete

I need to keep the last 5 search results of a user in a table.
I wrote a script to remove other rows, but it didn't work:

```
DELETE FROM         
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY search_time DESC) AS row_number;
    FROM
        history_user
    WHERE
        user_id = 188
WHERE row_number>5
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Proper syntax [as detailed in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-delete.html):

```
DELETE FROM history_user h
USING (
    SELECT pk_id, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY search_time DESC) AS rn;
    FROM   history_user
    WHERE  user_id = 188
    ) sub
WHERE sub.rn > 5
AND   h.pk_id = sub.pk_id;
```

Where `pk_id` is any (combination of) column(s) that is *unique*. Might be `user_id`, `search_time` in your case - or, more conveniently, a surrogate primary key.

For just a **single** `user_id` you can simplify to:

```
DELETE FROM history_user h
USING (
    SELECT pk_id
    FROM   history_user
    WHERE  user_id = 188
    ORDER  BY search_time DESC
    OFFSET 5
    ) sub
WHERE h.pk_id = sub.pk_id;
```

On the other hand, to deal with **multiple** users at once, you need to add `PARTITION BY` to your window function:

```
DELETE FROM history_user h
USING (
    SELECT pk_id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                                     ORDER BY search_time DESC) AS rn;
    FROM   history_user
    ) sub
WHERE sub.rn > 5
AND   h.pk_id = sub.pk_id;
```